# Promise inside loop in nodejs isn't working as expected

Tags: node.js, promise

I have array of events, for each value there may/may not query fires to get data.

```
var eventTypes = [["write","write","write","write"],["write","write","read","write"]];
_.each(eventTypes,function(obj){
        gettime(obj);
 });


gettime=function(events){
   var resultArray = [];
   _.each(events,function(event){
      if(event === "read"){
         resultArray.push(makesqlquery(event));
      }else{
         resultArray.push({"time":current_time})
      }
   });
   q.all(resultArray).then(function(finalResult){
        insertIntoPostgreSQL(finalResult);
   });
}

makesqlquery = function(event){
   var deferred = q.defer();
   sql.query("select time from events where eventtype ="+ event,
      function(result,error){
        if(error){
          deferred.reject(error);
        }else{
          deferred.resolve({time:result.time});
        }
    });
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

In the above code I'm able to push 1st set of data(`["write","write","write","write"]`) into `postgresql` database but not 2nd set(["write","write","read","write"]). Whenever I get `read` event in a set, I'm getting empty object. What would be the problem? For the above example I should have 8 records in `postgresql`, but I see only first array's four data.

**More Info:** `insertIntoPostgreSQL()` function will get list of objects and insert each object into database. This operation is workin fine.

I tried use two console stmt as

```
console.log("sql result:"result);
deferred.resolve({time:result.time});
```

and

```
console.log("Before Insert:"JSON.stringigy(resultArray));
q.all(resultArray).then(function(finalResul‌​t){
```

I get result as in the following order.

> Before insert:[{"source":{}},{"source":{}},{"source":{}},{"source":{}}]
>
> Before insert:[{}]
>
> sql result:{time:"2015-07-10 00:00:00"}

Comment: I may be missing something else, but are you sure that the insertIntoPostgreSQL function has the select query in 'finalResult'? That would imply the promise is getting fulfilled.

Comment: `function(finalResult){insertIntoPostgreSQL(finalResult);});` callback isn't even executing for `read` event.

Comment: Currently, what your code is saying is that after -all- events are done (q.all) then the anonymous function(finalResult) will be triggered. This should be happening just once. finalResult should then contain ther time:result from your select callbacks.

Comment: The promise returned by `q.all()` is probably taking the error path. Try adding a handler to make an error observable, ie `.then(insertIntoPostgreSQL, errorHandler)`.

Comment: I have updated my question with more info. @Spork

Comment: Error handler says `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined]` @Roamer-1888

Answer (score 1):

As Roamer-1888 mentioned in the comments, definitely add an error handler for your `Q.all`. The basic structure of your promise seems to be fine, the error is somewhere else.

It looks like the `result` in your `sql.query` callback is not quite what you expect, as it is read as `undefined`. Because of an error there, Q.all is not getting resolved, therefore nothing gets added to your database.

Comment: I tried use two console stmt as `console.log("sql result:"result);deferred.resolve({time:result.time});` and `console.log("Before insert:"JSON.stringigy(resultArray));q.all(resultArray).then(function(finalResult){` I get result as in the following order. `Before insert:[{"source":{}},{"source":{}},{"source":{}}]` in next line `sql result:{time:"2015-07-10 00:00:00"}`

Comment: You could try `deferred.resolve({time:result || 0});` and see if that sends `q.all(...)` down the success path. If so, you should see a `0` appear in the database. The real fix lies elsewhere of course but at least this will give you more confidence in the overall process.

Comment: Or maybe `deferred.resolve({time:result.time || 0});`?